# Issue in receiving Push Notifications in iOS

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, javapns

I face some issues in receiving push notification from 2 different servers. The servers' backend code is written in Java and I have used `javapns` library for apple push notifications. When I receive notification (from one of the servers), I get the following log statements,

> 2015-11-06/12:17:15.829 [DEBUG] [] [javapns.notification.Payload] - Adding alert [Alert Message]
>
> 2015-11-06/12:17:16.054 [DEBUG] [] [javapns.communication.ConnectionToAppleServer] - `Creating SSLSocketFactory`
>
> 2015-11-06/12:17:16.127 [DEBUG] [] [javapns.communication.ConnectionToAppleServer] - `Creating SSLSocket to gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195`
>
> 2015-11-06/12:17:16.776 [DEBUG] [] [javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager] - `Initialized Connection to Host: [gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com] Port: [2195]: 6644621c[SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL: Socket[addr=gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com/17.172.232.45,port=2195,localport=57181]]`
>
> 2015-11-06/12:17:16.778 [DEBUG] [] [javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager] - `Building Raw message from deviceToken and payload`
>
> 2015-11-06/12:17:16.779 [DEBUG] [] [javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager] - `Built raw message ID 1 of total length 91`
>
> 2015-11-06/12:17:16.779 [DEBUG] [] [javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager] - `Attempting to send notification: {"aps":{"alert":"Alert Message"}}`
>
> 2015-11-06/12:17:16.779 [DEBUG] [] [javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager] -   `to device: e61aa2adfa16449f894b317ea3b4dbbfe4589000abdec7c8c0eb3c7b92654e4c`
>
> 2015-11-06/12:17:17.696 [DEBUG] [] [javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager] - `Flushing`
>
> 2015-11-06/12:17:17.696 [DEBUG] [] [javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager] - `At this point, the entire 91-bytes message has been streamed out successfully through the SSL connection`
>
> 2015-11-06/12:17:17.696 [DEBUG] [] [javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager] - `Notification sent on first attempt`
>
> 2015-11-06/12:17:17.696 [DEBUG] [] [javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager] - Reading responses
>
> 2015-11-06/12:17:22.698 [DEBUG] [] [javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager] - Closing connection

But, when I do not receive the notification (from the other server), I get the following log,

> 2015-11-20/13:37:50.539 [DEBUG] [] [javapns.notification.Payload] - Adding alert [Alert Message]
>
> 2015-11-20/13:37:50.543 [DEBUG] [] [javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager] - Reading responses
>
> 2015-11-20/13:37:50.545 [DEBUG] [] [javapns.notification.PushNotificationManager] - Closing connection

Here, I am not getting any log statements regarding the creation of SSL Socket Factory or other highlighted texts. And the `ConnectionToAppleServer` class is not getting called. So, I doubt whether I am missing any jar files.

**NOTE:** I am using same development certificate in both the servers.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: From your log **Attempting to send notification: {"aps":{"alert":"Alert Message"}} ** means you are getting notification, so you need to check in didRecieveRemoteNotification method.

Comment: In the second log, I am not getting this message -  `Attempting to send notification: {"aps":{"alert":"Alert Message"}}`. And thus, I am not receiving any notifications.

Comment: post some code what you have implemented, then it will be easy to identify or debug yourself then you can understand where you are getting problem, I faced the same issue when I was working with APNs, by debugging I got to know where I went wrong.

Comment: Actually I have same code and certificate in both the servers. But from one server I am receiving notifications. And from another server, I am not receiving anything. So, I think I am missing some jar files. But I could not find which jar files are missing.

Comment: I am using  `Push.alert(message, keystorePath, password, productionStatus, deviceToken);` to send message to the APNS server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not with the developer certificates or any jar files related to iOS. The server code was written to send notifications to both android and iOS. And some jar files related with android were missing. So, in the back end, the control dint reach the part where the code to send iOS notifications was written. That was the problem. Once, those jar files are added, everything works fine!!